# Visual Basic editor command icon is always disabled

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-9.3, vb.net, vba

I recently installed ArcGIS 9.3 in a PC with Windows 7.0. I opened an existing mxd file within which I developed some toolbars for a project. Each icon of a toolbar has behind it a VBA and ArcObjects code. Unfortunately, I noticed that icons are all missing and the symbol of each icon has been replaced by a red circle with a slahed line and the commnad of Visual basic editor under the Tools menu is always disabled-inactive, thus I cannot get in the VBA editor.

Can anybody help me please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that is an indication that VBA is not installed correctly or at all.

See this ESRI help document: http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/17844

Answer (score 1):

The Esri Knowledgebase article #17844 link from other answer and a dozen other places on the net are broken and I haven't been able to find a new source. However I was able to use the VBA Compatibility package from ArcGIS 10.4.1 on an ArcGIS 9.3 machine and get to the macro editor.

What I did:

- Download ArcGIS_VBA_Compatibility_1031_145766 from My Esri
- unpack with 7-zip and extract to folder
- drill down to setup.exe and run it

I had to run the install twice, but then it worked. The unpacking step might not be necessary.